# Como filtrar uma tabela que esta dentro de uma coluna?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Como filtrar uma tabela que esta dentro de uma coluna, só quero filtrar pelo cabeçalho da coluna que a tabela esta olhando o codigo dar para entender

```
<p:column styleClass="anexosMovimento"
            filterBy="#{anexo.descricaoAnexo}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="text-align: center;" filterable="true">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Anexos" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:panelGroup id="anexosMovimento">
                    <p:dataTable tableStyle="table-layout:auto;width: 100%;"
                        var="anexo" value="#{movimento.anexos}" id="tabelaAnexos"
                        filterable="true"
                        rendered="#{tjse:length(movimento.anexos) > 0}" rowKey="#{anexo}"
                        styleClass="tabelaAnexos" emptyMessage="Nenhum anexo encontrado.">
                        <p:column styleClass="checkAnexo">
                            <h:panelGroup id="checks">
                                <h:outputText value="#{status.index}" rendered="false" />
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="on" value="#{appBean.sempreTrue}"
                                    style="display: #{tjse:estaNaLista(anexo, expedicaoMandadoBean.anexosSelecionadosUni)?'inline':'none'};">
                                    <p:ajax partialSubmit="false"
                                        listener="#{expedicaoMandadoBean.selecionarAnexo}"
                                        event="change" update="checks, nome, descricao" />
                                    <f:attribute name="anexo" value="#{anexo}" />
                                    <f:attribute name="marcado" value="#{appBean.sempreTrue}" />
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="off"
                                    value="#{appBean.sempreFalse}"
                                    style="display: #{tjse:estaNaLista(anexo, expedicaoMandadoBean.anexosSelecionadosUni)?'none':'inline'};">
                                    <p:ajax partialSubmit="false"
                                        listener="#{expedicaoMandadoBean.selecionarAnexo}"
                                        event="change" update="checks, nome, descricao" />
                                    <f:attribute name="anexo" value="#{anexo}" />
                                    <f:attribute name="marcado" value="#{appBean.sempreFalse}" />
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="nomeArquivo">
                            <h:panelGroup id="nome">
                                <p:commandLink ajax="false" title="Download"
                                    styleClass="OutputLabelLink" rendered="#{anexo.anexoBinario}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{anexo.descricaoAnexo}" />
                                    <p:fileDownload
                                        value="#{tjse:downloadFile(anexo.arquivo, 'application/pdf', anexo.nome)}" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink title="Abrir íntegra" update=":dlgIntegraId"
                                    rendered="#{not anexo.anexoBinario and not anexo.acordao}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('dlgIntegra').show()" partialSubmit="true"
                                    styleClass="OutputLabelLink" process="@this">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{anexo.descricaoAnexo}" />
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{viewScope.textoIntegra}" value="#{anexo.texto}" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink title="Abrir Acórdão" update=":visualizaAcordao"
                                    rendered="#{not anexo.anexoBinario and anexo.acordao}"
                                    oncomplete="PF('dlgAcordao').show()" partialSubmit="true"
                                    styleClass="OutputLabelLink" process="@this">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{anexo.descricaoAnexo}" />
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{viewScope.dataMovimento}"
                                        value="#{anexo.chave.data}" />
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{viewScope.numeroProcesso}"
                                        value="#{anexo.chave.numeroProcesso}" />
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{viewScope.codMovimento}"
                                        value="#{anexo.chave.codigo}" />
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{viewScope.seqMovimento}"
                                        value="#{anexo.chave.sequenciaMovimento}" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="tipoArquivo">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{(anexo.tipoAnexo) ne null ? anexo.tipoAnexo.descricao : anexo.descricaoAnexo }" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column styleClass="descricaoArquivo">
                            <h:panelGroup id="descricao">
                                <h:outputText value="#{anexo.anexoBinario?anexo.descricao:'-'}" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
```